# Using XTemplate with SimpleStore in Ext

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am currently adding some functionality to some old code. There used to be a template which took a flat array of items and spat out some HTML, now the data is coming from a simple store which reads some JSON..

```
var allwords = [
    ['abacteriano', 'abacteriano'],
    ['abacterial', 'abacteriano'],
    ['abciximab', 'abciximab'], ...
]
```

So my simplestore goes like this:

```
    termStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['term', 'lookup'],
        data: allwords
    });
```

This definitly works fine as I use the termStore in a combobox. However I am having difficulty getting it to play with an XTemplate.

It seems the syntax in extjs doesn't play well with SO, so this bit wont be in a code block...

So I guess I'll describe it :p

Essentially its a simple template which tries to get values out of the passed collection by doing {term}

I then try and apply it by doing:

```
tpl.overwrite(Ext.get("contentbox"), termStore);
```

This gives me a JS error of "invalid object initializer"

Answer (score 0):

XTemplate works with simple objects or arrays, not afaik, simplestores. Try binding it to your allwords array instead.